Smooth Video Switching Without Screen Flashing in HTML5 Video Player
I'm working on a portfolio website where I showcase my videos. The main feature includes a larger main video and smaller video thumbnails. When I click on a thumbnail, the main video should switch to the clicked video's source without causing a screen flash. When I click on the video thumbnails, the screen flashes momentarily as the video source switches. It seems like the video element is being reloaded each time, which I want to avoid for a smoother user experience.
Here is my code:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const mainVideo = document.getElementById("main-video");
    const smallVideos = document.querySelectorAll(".video-item");

    smallVideos.forEach(videoItem => {
        videoItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const newSrc = this.getAttribute("data-video-src");

            if (mainVideo.querySelector("source").src !== newSrc) {
                mainVideo.pause();
                mainVideo.querySelector("source").src = newSrc;
                mainVideo.load();
                mainVideo.play();
            }
        });
    });
});
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #333;
}

main {
    padding: 2rem 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.video-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-video video {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.small-videos {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 900px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.small-videos .video-item {
    flex: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.small-videos img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.divider {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 4rem auto 1rem;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem 0;
}

footer p {
    margin: 0;
    color: #333;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .main-video video {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .small-videos {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .small-videos .video-item {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    .divider {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Petr FPV Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="video-container">
            <div class="main-video">
                <video id="main-video" controls>
                    <source src="cabo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="small-videos">
                <div class="video-item" data-video-src="grass.mp4">
                    <img src="grass.png" alt="Grass video thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="video-item" data-video-src="sunset.mp4">
                    <img src="sunset.png" alt="Sunset video thumbnail">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <div class="divider"></div>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2024 My Name. All rights reserved.</p>
    </footer>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



I tried pausing the video before changing the source, and preloading the video using the fetch APIs. When clicking a thumbnail, the main video should switch to the new source without flashing or reloading the entire video element.

Instead of changing the src attribute, why not create multiple <video> elements and blend between them via CSS?
When you change the src, the browser has to starts fetching the new video. The screen "flashes" because of this.
